# How to use OmniFaces 1.6 in two WARs in one EAR?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, cdi, ear, omnifaces

JBoss 7.1, OmniFaces 1.6, Eclipse Kepler, CDI 1.0

I have found the following situation with new Omnifaces 1.6, when I updated from OmniFaces 1.5 to OmniFaces 1.6. I suppose it has something to do with new interesting CDI features of OmniFaces 1.6.

I have two JSF based WAR projects in one EAR archive, both projects have OmniFaces as dependency and they both will be deployed. In deployment, OmniFaces 1.6 ends up in `/WEB-INF/lib` of both WAR projects. At start of JBoss the `IllegalArgumentException` was thrown.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Registering converter 'class org.omnifaces.converter.ListConverter' failed, duplicates converter ID 'omnifaces.ListConverter' of other converter 'class org.omnifaces.converter.ListConverter'.
    at org.omnifaces.cdi.converter.ConverterExtension.processConverters(ConverterExtension.java:78)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections$13.work(SecureReflections.java:264)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.run(SecureReflectionAccess.java:52)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.runAsInvocation(SecureReflectionAccess.java:137)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections.invoke(SecureReflections.java:260)
    at org.jboss.weld.introspector.jlr.WeldMethodImpl.invokeOnInstance(WeldMethodImpl.java:170)
    at org.jboss.weld.introspector.ForwardingWeldMethod.invokeOnInstance(ForwardingWeldMethod.java:51)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.MethodInjectionPoint.invokeOnInstanceWithSpecialValue(MethodInjectionPoint.java:154)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:241)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:229)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.notify(ObserverMethodImpl.java:207)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.notifyObservers(BeanManagerImpl.java:569)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.fireEvent(BeanManagerImpl.java:559)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractContainerEvent.fire(AbstractContainerEvent.java:60)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractDefinitionContainerEvent.fire(AbstractDefinitionContainerEvent.java:38)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.ProcessManagedBeanImpl.fire(ProcessManagedBeanImpl.java:30)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.AbstractBeanDeployer.deploy(AbstractBeanDeployer.java:123)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployment.deployBeans(BeanDeployment.java:204)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.deployBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:344)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.WeldContainer.start(WeldContainer.java:82)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.services.WeldService.start(WeldService.java:76)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

If I remove one WAR project, then the exception dissapears and I can use the other WAR project in EAR.

Is it possible to use OmniFaces 1.6 in more as one project, and deploy to JBoss 7.1.1 in one EAR?

Comment: This problem is already identified and we're currently working on it: https://code.google.com/p/omnifaces/issues/detail?id=251 Today or tomorrow there will be a 1.6.1 with the mandatory fixes.

Comment: Thank you, I will be waiting for a fix!

Comment: I fixed it. Please try 1.6.1 snapshot: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/omnifaces/omnifaces/1.6.1-SNAPSHOT/ If it works for you I will post an answer with explanation.

Comment: Sorry, it still isn't entirely fixed. I will look at it.

Comment: Now, deployment problem and converter/validator issue is fixed with current snapshot, but `@ViewScoped` doesn't work as intented in this EAR+2WAR construct. I'm looking at it.

Comment: Thank you, I'll test snapshot, but for futher development I am waiting for both CDI fixes (Viewscoped and converter/validator) in OmniFaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This bug has been fixed in 1.6.1. There's quite a story behind this bug, so I just wrote a blog on that: [CDI behaved unexpectedly in EAR, so OmniFaces 1.6.1 released!](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2013/10/cdi-behaved-unexpectedly-in-ear-so.html)

Summarized: CDI context isn't WAR-wide, but EAR-wide. As to the particular exception you faced, it's because there was only one CDI `ConverterExtension` being loaded from one WAR which is then applied EAR-wide and thus processing all `@FacesConverter` classes from **both** WARs instead of the WAR where the CDI extension was being loaded from.

Note that this is not a problem in OmniFaces. This is a problem in the way how CDI works in EARs.

---

**Update**: as per issue [WELD-2143](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WELD-2143) this peculiar problem has finally been fixed in Weld 2.3.5. I have tested it in a patched WildFly 10.0.0 and confirmed that all OmniFaces CDI features which depend on an `Extension`, the `@ViewScoped`, `@Eager` and `@Param` work again in both WARs in a single EAR.

So, if you struggle with using aforementioned OmniFaces CDI features in an EAR with multiple WARs, make sure you upgrade Weld to at least version 2.3.5. The problem remains open in OpenWebBeans.

Comment: Thank you for quick response and bug fixes! Unfortunately I can not yet use 1.6.1. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19247876/required-fields-with-omnifaces-1-6-1