# Required fields with OmniFaces 1.6.1

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, omnifaces

Primefaces 3.5.16, JBoss 7.2.0, PE 0.7.1, Mojara 2.1.26, WELD-000900 1.1.10 (Final)
Web.xml has some configuration stuff, faces-config has languages bundles defined.

I have following dialog with some input fields and p:tabview:

```
<p:dialog>

  <h:form>
   <p:tabView binding="#{tabViewEL}"> 
    <p:messages autoUpdate="true"/> 
  <p:tab  title="tab1">

    <p:inputText value="#{bean.value1}" required="true" />
    <p:inputText value="#{bean.value2}" />
    <p:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.value3}">
       <f:selectItems value="#{bean.items1}"></f:selectItems>
    </p:selectOneMenu>
  </p:tab>
  <p:tab> ... </p:tab>
  </p:tabView>

  <p:commandButton value="ok" oncomplete="checkAndHide(xhr, status, args);" action="#{bean.action()}"/>
  </h:form>

</p:dialog>
```

If I click "ok" and I am using OmniFaces v. 1.5 or 1.6 it functions right. If I'm using 1.6.1 all required fields (and p:selectOneMenu without null-selected-Item) are marked red with errors "Value is required". How can I use 1.6.1 without validation errors ?

***Edit***  : I've tried to create an example but I've discovered another curious behavior of application. With OmniFaces 1.6 it functions right, but with 1.6.1 the input fields are not filled with values.

```
 OmnitestBean.java
 import java.io.Serializable;

 import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
 import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
 import javax.inject.Named;

 @Named
 @SessionScoped
 public class OmnitestBean implements Serializable{
private Integer value1 = 12;
private Integer value2 = 3;

public OmnitestBean (){
    System.out.println("Constru");
}

@PostConstruct
public void a(){
    value1 = 14;
    value2 = 30;
    System.out.println("in postconstruct");
}

public Integer getValue1() {
    return value1;
}

public void setValue1(Integer value1) {
    this.value1 = value1;
}

public Integer getValue2() {
    return value2;
}

public void setValue2(Integer value2) {
    this.value2 = value2;
}

public void action(){
    System.out.println("In action");
}

 }
```

omnifaces.xhtml:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" 
xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions">
<h:head />
<body>
<h:form id="editPopForm">
    <p:messages id="messages2" autoUpdate="true"></p:messages>
    <p:inputText value="#{omnitestBean.value1}" required="true" />
    <p:inputText value="#{omnitestBean.value2}" />

    <p:commandButton process="@form" action="#{omnitestBean.action()}" value="OK"
         update="@form" id="editFormOkButt" />
</h:form>
```

Comment: This is strange. Will look at it. By the way, shouldn't that be a `<h:form>`? Please post code in such way that I can copypaste it unmodified into a `<h:body>`. With or without `checkAndHide`.

Comment: Sorry, can't reproduce it. Please post a true SSCCE (i.e. code which I (and you!) can just copy'n'paste'n'run in a blank playground WAR environment without making non-obvious modifications/stubbing).

Comment: Thank you!I will try. Unfortunately I can not send my code in original form.

Comment: Can you please reconfirm that this construct works fine with OmniFaces 1.6 in a WAR?

Comment: Yes double checked already.

Comment: I did forget to say that tabview is used. I've changed code, it is not SSCCE yet but perhaps helps.

Comment: Sorry, still not reproducible. It's also not a true SSCCE. I had to add `<p:dialog visible="true">` (or to remove whole `<p:dialog>`), I had to remove all input `value` attributes, I had to replace `<f:selectItems>` by a bunch of hardcoded `<f:selectItem>` entries, I had to remove `<p:commandButton action>` (so that the whole works without any bean). I had to remove `<p:commandButton oncomplete>` (because it didn't exist for me). I had to remove `<p:tab>...</p:tab>` because it was invalid. Then it runs, but still not reproducible. I get only error for 1st input, when I fill it, it succeeds.

Comment: I'll try to reproduce an error with a simple example and then I'll post it.

Comment: Oh, I also added `autoUpdate="true"` to the `<p:messages>` so that they at least show up.

Comment: Sorry for the first poor example. I edited my answer with an SSCCE.

Comment: Sorry, they appear just filled (Mojarra 2.1.26 + PrimeFaces 3.5 (not 3.5.16) no PrimeFaces Extensions). `web.xml` contains only faces servlet, no configuration stuff. `faces-config.xml` is empty. How does those `binding` attributes play a role in the SSCCE? Does the problem for you disappear when you remove them? If not, then there's no point of including them in the SSCCE as they make it possibly confusing. The same applies to most of `id`, `widgetVar`, `style` attributes, `cache="false"`, `disabled="false"`, and the double `<p:messages>` by the way.

Comment: Update, to be more clear. I have no idea why the behavior is so. The `WAR` with example is used inside an `EAR`. I wrote my configuration on top of the question. Maybe I have bad luck :-)

Comment: Sorry, still no-repro with the new SSCCE (much better!) in WAR in EAR. Only difference is that I don't use PrimeFaces Extensions and have PrimeFaces 3.5 (3.5.16 is for Elite/Pro users only).

Comment: In order to exclude the one and other, can you please try the following things on your own? 1) Unpack OmniFaces JAR, remove `javax.enterprise.inject.spi.Extension` file from `/META-INF/services`, repack it using ZIP/RAR tool and retry (this disables all CDI extensions which were modified in 1.6.1 as compared to 1.6). If you still face the same problem, then 2) Unpack OmniFaces JAR, open `/META-INF/faces-config.xml` for editing and remove the entire `<application-factory>` entry, repack and retry (this changes the way how converters/validators are resolved back to default).

Comment: I've tried your suggestion the 2nd option helps. The 1st option had no effect

Comment: Interesting. Do you see chance to provide the complete EAR (with the SSCCE) as a download somewhere? Else just mail it on my nickname at gmail.

Comment: With my best guess, something seriously failed as to resolving the converter for `Integer.class`. Do you happen to have converters with a `forClass` in the application?

Comment: Yes, but not for `Integer.class`. Only for Pojo.

Comment: Unfortunately I can not send the EAR (it has another code). I could try to reproduce an error in a simple environment.

Comment: I've tested with 1.6.2  as a precaution but unfortunately I become the error.

Comment: I'd love to fix it, but sorry, I can't fix it if I can't reproduce it. An SSCCE in EAR flavor is really the best way.

Comment: I've found the error. As you said it was integer converter. Thank you for your help! I've written a short explanation as an answer. But interestingly this converter was called only with 1.6.1 and so on. Was the behavior of converter/validators changed in OmniFaces ?

Comment: OmniFaces 1.6 searches and registers every `@FacesConverter` and `@FacesValidator` eligible for CDI/EJB injection. Your problem is however still strange. I can't reproduce it.

Comment: I could reproduce the problem in a much simpler environment. I try to customize the project and then provide you download link.

Comment: I've send you an example EAR .

Comment: Saw it. Will look closer at it when time allows it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As BalusC noted in his comment it has something to do with Integer converter.
I had the following dummy integer converter, it was hidden somewhere  in project.

```
@FacesConverter(value = "someDummyConverter")
public class SomeDummyConverter extends IntegerConverter {
public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component,
        String value) {
    Integer intValue = (Integer) super.getAsObject(context, component, value);
    return intValue;
}

@Override
public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object o) {
    return null;
}
```

}

If I used OmniFaces 1.5 or 1.6 this converter was not called. With OmniFaces 1.6.1, 1.6.2, 1.6.3 the converter was called. If I deleted the converter, the problem was disappeared.